# Send Data From my website to an external page of another website using PHP

Tags: php, api, request

all my problem is that I wanna send data from my website to this website's page :

```
http://www.womo.com.au/external-review.php?id=MDAxMTcyNjcw
```

how I can do this ? and is it possible ? cuz as I have seen this website forms validation's all in javascript and dunno how to handle it ?

thanks.

Comment: if that is your site then yes, if not then may be you can not send to that webpage.
Cuz if you want to send data from your domain to that domain, you will have to enable the CORS on that server page.
then you can send data using ajax or whichever method you like best.
Data is submitted to
`http://www.womo.com.au/external-review.php?id=MDAxMTcyNjcw`

Comment: no this not my website !  this is womo.com.au a feedback system for companies ... and I have a website almost like it where I wanna add an option called share to womo where people can share the feedback they got on my website to womo ... so I'm wondering if that is possible ?  if not please explain me why cuz I love to have info about that and I'll appreciate that .

Thank you.

Comment: what i said cuz some days i ago, i ran in to same problem. where i had to use jQuery CORS for enabling me to send data.
I am not certain, but i want you to try send data using jquery Ajax.
if i am not wrong, Server Only accepts posts if made under there own domain, if someother domain posted a request it will not accept the posted request.
May be i am wrong and there are no security measures then sure try your luck.

Comment: Ok I'll try it but you have any idea on how I can submit the form in http://www.womo.com.au/external-review.php?id=MDAxMTcyNjcw 
after filling from the data I will sent from my website using ajax ?

Comment: check the answer i gave, that might can give you some insight that how you can achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do that, just make a `testPosting.html` file,
Create your form using all the inputs that are required to send.
See the screenshot for the posted fields.
This data is posted when i submitted the form after filling it.

[image]

Now as you can see 14 fields are posted, so you need to make 13 inputs and 1 textarea.

use click function for the button of submit e.g

```
$('#buttonID').click(function(e){
e.PreventDefault();
//store values of inputs in a variable
var data = {
FirstName = $('#FirstName').val(); // you can more better then that if you know how
//Add the rest of the data
};
});
```

then you can use jQuery Ajax to send data.

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://www.womo.com.au/external-review.php?id=MDAxMTcyNjcw",
data:data, //this data will be the variable that you create in which all the forms inputs datas are stored.
type: "POST"
}).done(function(result) {
//do stuff if some result has returned
});
```

i just gave the rough idea.
Oh you must use this line in script on top of you JS scrips

```
jQuery.support.cors = true; // force cross-site scripting (as of jQuery 1.5)
```

My code is not perfect but you get the idea what i am trying to say, you might can start from here, and do stuff of your own..